# Sed replace pattern results in unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to fill the value of a config from a remote machine using this command:

```
ssh www@test-www-01.abc.com echo -e \"password\\n\" \| sudo -S sed -i 's,test_cluster: {key: ""},test_cluster: {key: "key1"},g' /home/www/config.js
```

I am able to login to the machine successfully but `sed` returns an error:

```
[sudo] password for www: sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What's the meaning of `echo -e \"password\\n\"` ?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to protect the some quotes:

```
ssh www@test-www-01.abc.com echo -e \"password\\n\" \| sudo -S sed -i \'s,test_cluster: {key: \"\"},test_cluster: {key: \"key1\"},g\' /home/www/config.js
```

Seems to work correctly.